# Eclipse: set breakpoint with JDIDebugModel

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I'm trying to set a breakpoint programmatically in my Eclipse plug-in. It seems to work fine; the marker is added to the editor sidebar and a breakboint entry is also added to the Breakpoints view. But when I debug the program, the VM does not suspend at the breakpoint. Furthermore, if I suspend the VM before the call to `getNormalFlowFunction` and then try to step into 
the method, the VM suddenly resumes and runs until the end of the program. Unfortunately, there is no error message.
I assume, that something is wrong with my parameters, but from the documentation and sample code I found, I can not tell, what's going wrong. Any ideas?

Here is how I'm setting the breakpoint

```
IJavaMethodBreakpoint breakpoint = JDIDebugModel.createMethodBreakpoint(resource, className, methodName, methodSignature, entry, exit, nativeOnly, lineNumber, charStart, charEnd, hitCount, register, attrs);
```

I use these parameter values:

`resource: L/code/src/code/Main.java
class: Main
method: getNormalFlowFunction
signature: (QString;)QString;
resource: L/code/src/code/Main.java
entry: true
exit: false
nativeOnly: false
line: 12
charStart: 248
charEnd: 405
hit count: 0
register: true
attrs: {}`

The target class looks like this:

```
package code;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Bla");
        String outSet = getNormalFlowFunction("Hallo");
        System.out.println(outSet);
        anotherMethod();
    }

    public static String getNormalFlowFunction(String inSet) {
        System.out.println("getNormalFlowFunction");
        String outSet = inSet + inSet;
        return outSet;
    }

    public static void anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println("Another method");
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**:
I also noticed, that when I set a breakpoint manually before launching the debugger, the manually set breakpoint gets the little checkmark, but my programmatically set breakpoint does not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there were several problems with my parameters. I had to debug into JDT to find out, how the parameters have to look like

1. class has to be the fully qualified name
2. signature needs to be resolved. I copied code from ToggleBreakpointAdapter
3. chartStart and charEnd have to point to the method name. charStart points to the g of getNormalFlowFunction and charEnd points behind the n

Here is an updated list of the parameters:

`resource: L/code/src/code/Main.java
class: code.Main
method: getNormalFlowFunction
signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
resource: L/code/src/code/Main.java
entry: true
exit: true
nativeOnly: false
line: 12
charStart: 269
charEnd: 290
hit count: 0
register: true
attrs: null`